# Uneven intervals for a score

Tags: classification, categorical-data, descriptive-statistics, categorical-encoding

I want to create categories to classify some variables into "Good", "Regular" and "Bad" performance.

Each variable has its own measure and its own reference value (like a target value indicating what the variable suppose to be if the performance was good).

I'd like to use the target value to create the category for each variable instead of using the minimum and maximum value of the observations to make the intervals, because it would lead me to have intervals with the same class width.

Why do I want this? Because I need categories that reflects some learning curve. Going from Regular to Good isn't as easy as going from Bad to Regular. This would take into account the effort needed to change the status quo.

Once I have these uneven intervals (categories), same for all set of variables, I could have a standard measure for all and make a dimension reduction using any technique. I know I could do the dimension reduction before the variable classification into Good, Regular and Bad, but I need first to scale the variables into a performance measure.

**So, the question is:**

*How can I calculate the categories (intervals) for each variable taking into account: 1. The target value (as a reference point) and 2. Intervals can no be even (uneven class width)?*

Suppose the target value for a variable is 60, then any value close to 60 would be classified as "Good". But if in my data there isn't any value close to that, any point would be classified as "Good"

Answer (score 0):

I would try 2 things:

1. Look at the distributions of the variables for clues. These may be plain multi-modal, or at least look like composed of multiple 'peaks'. If so, I would use mixture modeling (e.g. package `mclust` for `R`) to determine breaks between the groups (intervals).
2. If the above does not work and your distributions look like perfect theoretical curves, then I would just pick intervals arbitrarily, perhaps use information external to the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! But neither suggestion includes the reference value (the target value). 
Suppose the target value for a variable is 60, then any value close to 60 would be classified as "Good". But if in my data there isn't any value close to that, any point would be classified as "Good"